# Implementation of script using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm want to add some effects when I clik a button using jquery.I wrote this code on a file named script1.js:(authentication/views/javascript/script1)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".button" ).mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).addClass("active");
    });
    $(".button").mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
    })
  });
```

when i call this script in signin.ejs using :(authentication/views)

```
<script src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/script1.js"></script>
```

The button still fixed and no effect was shown.
Style.css:(authentication/views/style)

```
.active {
    background-color:#556677;
}

.button {
    background-color:#8CC6D7;
    border:1px solid #5EB6DD;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
}
```

Then I added a folder named jquery (authentication/views/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4)
On the app.js(authentication/app.js(nodejs)),I added these lines:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/views/style'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/views/javascript'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/views/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4'));
```

Comment: Your `button` is a `<button>` or `.button`? you define `.button` in css which is a class, but in your js you use `$( "button" )` which is a selector of `<button>`.

Comment: You need to you `active` after `button` styling in css. It is cascading rule. In case of classes the that comes later is applied.

Comment: First things first, did the js file load? were you able to access it while running the program?

Comment: @CodeFighter: 
this is my problem the file js isn't been loaded.

Comment: Did you check the path of file in application? may be the browser when you are running the app? Is the path correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working:

If it is `button` tag

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("button").mouseenter(function() {
     $(this).addClass("active");
   })
   $("button").mouseleave(function() {
     $(this).removeClass("active");
   })
 });
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #556677;
}
button {
  background-color: #8CC6D7;
  border: 1px solid #5EB6DD;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click Me</button>
```

else

If **button is class**, *keep active class after button in css* also jquery as `$(".button")`:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".button").mouseenter(function() {
     $(this).addClass("active");
   })
   $(".button").mouseleave(function() {
     $(this).removeClass("active");
   })
 });
```

```css
.button {

  background-color: #8CC6D7;

  border: 1px solid #5EB6DD;

  border-radius: 5px;

  width: 100px;

  height: 40px;

  margin-left: auto;

  margin-right: auto;

  font-family: Arial;

  font-size: 15px;

}

.active {

  background-color: #556677;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="button" value="click me"></input>
```